# Proving $(\forall r\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q})(\exists !n\in\mathbb{Z})(|r-n|<\frac{1}{2})$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

My goal is to prove that $(\forall r\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q})(\exists !n\in\mathbb{Z})(|r-n|<\frac{1}{2})$. The solution I came up with, I think, is more intuitive than the one provided by the book (provided at the end of this post for reference), but I'm interested in how I might polish up my own proof.

*Proof.* Suppose $r\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$ and $|r-n|<1/2$. By definition,
$$
|r-n|<1/2=\tag{1}
\begin{cases}
r-n<1/2 & \text{if $r\geq n$}\\
n-r<1/2 & \text{if $r<n$}.
\end{cases}
$$
That is, $r-1/2<n$ and $n<r+1/2$ or simply
$$
r-\frac{1}{2}<n<r+\frac{1}{2}.\tag{2}
$$
Thus, we have that $\operatorname{dist}(r-1/2,r+1/2)=1$. Since an irrational number plus a rational number is irrational, we see that
$$
n\in\bigl(\lfloor r-1/2\rfloor, \lceil r+1/2\rceil\bigr),\tag{3}
$$
where $n$ is an integer. Furthermore, $\lceil r+1/2\rceil-\lfloor r-1/2\rfloor=2$, guaranteeing that the $n$ in $(3)$ is unique, as desired. $\Box$

> How does this look? Comments? Critiques? Better way to polish it?

---

---

**Proof in book:** Given $r$, let $a$ be the closest integer to $r$ less than $r$, and let $b$ be the closest integer to $r$ greater than $r$. That is, let $a=\lfloor r\rfloor$ and $b=\lceil r\rceil$. Hence, $b=a+1$. Clearly the distance between $r$ and any integer other than $a$ or $b$ is greater than $1$ so cannot be less than $1/2$. Furthermore, since $r$ is irrational, it cannot be exactly half-way between $a$ and $b$, so exactly one of $r-a<1/2$ and $b-r<1/2$ holds.

Comment: The proof provided in the book is very elegant and more intuitive to me. You are starting your proof by assuming that the existence of $n$.

Comment: There isn't a problem doing that though is there? After all, it's a uniqueness proof, not an existence one. But I think my phrasing it with logical symbolism introduced that "existential hiccup"; that is, the problem in the book asks me to prove the $n$ is unique, not that it exists and is unique. Interesting subtlety.

Comment: Your phrasing suggests that you have to prove both existence and uniqueness.

Comment: @iHubble Right, that's what I meant by "existential hiccup"--my introducing the $\exists !x$ notation made it a uniqueness *and* existence proof, something the book managed to do but my proof neglects. I think my proof is alright for the uniqueness part, but the existential part is clearly a problem (if I am stick with that phrasing of the problem).

Comment: I think your proof is fine, but it could be cut down. You don't need to recall the definition of the absolute value for instance, it's superfluous. Just writing $|r - n| < 1/2 \implies \mathrm{dist}(r-1/2,r+1/2)$ is enough. I wouldn't use the $\mathrm{dist}(\cdot,\cdot)$ notation as it it not commonly used in general. You can simply say $|(r - 1/2) - (r + 1/2)| = 1$.

I still believe the book proof is better, but it was a good exercise to make up your own.

Comment: Yeah, it is a bit superfluous I suppose. Thanks for your comments and pointing out that subtle flaw I made. Appreciate it.